# How can I implement on_mose_move method in pgzero?

Tags: python, pgzero

So I'm trying to write a simple Arkanoid game, using only pgzero (!not pygame), and I want my paddle to move not using my keyboard, but using my mouse, so that the paddle moves left or right following the cursor, how can I do that and how to implement that as a class method?

I tried doing some research, watching multiple tutorials, and read documentation, it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`on_mouse_move`](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#on_mouse_move) is a callback function that is automatically called when the mouse is moved. See [Pygame Zero - Event Handling Hooks](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#event-handling-hooks).

Minimal example of drawing a rectangle at the position of the mouse cursor:

```py
import pgzrun

WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400
rect = Rect(0, 0, 30, 30)

def draw():
    screen.fill("black")
    screen.draw.filled_rect(rect, "red")

def on_mouse_move(pos, rel, buttons):
    rect.centerx = pos[0] 
    rect.centery = pos[1] 

pgzrun.go()
```

Minimal example of drawing an [`Actor`](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html#actor) at the position of the mouse cursor:

```py
import pgzrun

WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400
actor = Actor("image_name")

def draw():
    screen.fill("black")
    actor.draw()

def on_mouse_move(pos, rel, buttons):
    actor.x = pos[0]
    actor.y = pos[1]

pgzrun.go()
```

Comment: that helps a lot. could you also explain, how to make it only move left or right on the bottom of the screen? it moves my paddle up and down, which is not what I need, thank you

Comment: @maksonios `rect.centerx = pos[0]` for the 1st example and `apple.x = pos[0]` for the 2nd example. Of course you have to place the objects at the bottom e.g.: `rect.bottom =  400`